# Grails 3 mail: Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: grails, yaml, jakarta-mail, grails-3.0, starttls

I know this question has been asked many times in many different places, but for some reason, I can't seem to get it to work. I realize what the issue is, I just can't seem to figure out the yaml syntax or something simple like that.

I'm using Grails 3 with the "mail" plugin (2.0.0.RC6).

Here is a snippet of my application.yml:

```
grails:
    serverURL: <url>
    mail:
        host: <host>
        port: 587
        username: <username>
        password: <password>
        props:
            ? "mail.smtp.auth" : true
            ? "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" : true
            ? "mail.smtp.starttls.required" : true
            ? "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class" : "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
            ? "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback" : false
            ? "mail.smtp.port" : 587
```

I've tried many combinations of quotes with no luck. The `?` instead of a `-` indicates a map, which is what I want I think.

Here is the specific error message if it helps:

```
Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

        at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder.sendMessage(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:130)
        at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:53)
        at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:57)
        at website.UserController.register(UserController.groovy:60)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
```

This is a custom mail server running Postfix (first time setting it up). I am able to connect to it and send mail with Thunderbird. Thunderbird is using STARTTLS and port 587 to connect. As far as I know, I haven't been able to do just SSL/TLS.

**update:**

I've removed the factory config and fixed the yaml map stuff. Now I'm getting another error.

```
grails:
    serverURL: https://test.neonorb.com
    mail:
        host: test.neonorb.com
        port: 587
        username: neonorb
        password: pass
        props:
            mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
            mail.smtp.port: 587
```

Here is the exception:

```
unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder.sendMessage(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:130)
        at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:53)
        at grails.plugins.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:57)
        at website.UserController.register(UserController.groovy:60)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2046)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:711)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:598)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:525)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2041)
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        ... 12 common frames omitted
```

According to Google, this is because the certificate is self-signed, and Java doesn't trust it. My certificate is not self-signed, and is made from Let's Encrypt.

Comment: I got it, I had to add `mail.smtp.ssl.trust: <host>` to my properties.

Comment: You'll hind more information about this in the JavaMail FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

[Get rid of the socket factory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), they're long since obsolete.

Comment: Although this is an issue, and I removed it, it does not fix the problem.

Comment: There is no debug output, just the same error message. Is there a way to enable that?

Comment: Ya, sorry, find the JavaMail FAQ.  It's too hard to include the link when typing on my phone.

Comment: I've added `? "mail.debug" : true`, but that hasn't produced any debugging info. Maybe something to do with Grails and it's logging? I don't think the issue is with the API calls, but maybe how I do them? Could my YAML be incorrect?

Comment: Most likely your YAML is incorrect, but I don't know anything about that. Sorry.

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  Hopefully it's a relatively recent version or that could explain the problem as well.

Comment: Have you tried setting the properties in code instead of in the YAML file?